# Шифрование в FreeBSD после установки

Tags: шифрование, freebsd

Подскажите пожалуйста поставил FreeBSD 10.1 со стандартной ufs настроил веб-сервер. Как можно прозрачно зашифровать диск уже после настройки?
Например нужно зашифровать /usr/local/www, /var/db/mysql/, /home/user

**UPD.**

Поискал варианты, пожалуй буду пробовать с помощью fuse-encfs

Answer (score 1):

в [книге](http://muff.kiev.ua/files/books/Michael_Lucas_-_FreeBSD.pdf) Майкла Лукаса "FreeBSD. Подробное руководство" есть раздел "шифрование файловых систем", в нем описывается способ применения механизма geli

как говорится в [HandBook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/ru/books/handbook/disks-encrypting.html), эти механизмы(gbde и geli) налету шифруют в целом ФС и работают на уровне устройства, т.е. вам нужен будет отдельный раздел

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать зашифрованный раздел - [вот инструкция](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/ru/books/handbook/disks-encrypting.html) - перенести туда данные с нешифрованного раздела и изменить точку монтирования на новый раздел.

Проделать это, если в системе нет неразмеченного пространства нужного для шифрованного раздела объема, будет проблематично.